# Delegate send value back and push pop view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have controller A that push a controller to scan a code. When the code is scanned, it use a delegate to send the string back to controller A. Just after, the scan controller is poped. No problem for the moment.

But in the delegate of controller A, i need to check the result and use this data. In some case, another controller B must be push. This is not working. The screen stay on the scan controller, it just flicker 1s or less.

From what i understand, the delegate push the controller B while the scan controller is on screen and after this the scan controller call pop.

I have this in my scan controller:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(QrcodeHasFound:)]) {
    [self.delegate QrcodeHasFound:[metadataObj stringValue]];
}

[self.navigationController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And this in my delegate:

```
- (void)QrcodeHasFound:(NSString *)value{

// do some data use

ArticleController *mController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"articleController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mController animated:YES];
}
```

How should i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,  you're going to want to make sure that you are calling the delegate method on the main thread.  Right now, it appears as if you're calling the delegate method from a background thread (based on the fact that you're explicitly popping the view controller on the main thread).  In your delegate method, pushing a view controller on a background thread is likely to cause some issues.  Ex:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(QrcodeHasFound:)]) {
        [self.delegate QrcodeHasFound:[metadataObj stringValue]];
    }

    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

});
```

Another issue that may arise is that you'll be trying to push the view controller while the other one is popping.  To fix this, I would add a delay to the `pushViewController` method, or a delay to the delegate method.

Comment: With your code, the screen no more flicker and i can see that the delegate call controller B but is directly poped back to the scan controller. If i invert the two line to have first popViewControllerAnimated and call the delegate after, it's working fine. But i don't know if it's safe to call a delegate after this.

Comment: It will be perfectly safe.  Good observation about the ordering - glad that fixed your second issue.